# Determine if a positive integer $x$ is a product of a power of 2 and a power of 5. $f(x) = 2^n \cdot 5^n$

Tags: perfect-powers

Determine if a positive integer $x$ is a product of a power of $2$ and a power of $5$.

$f(x) = 2^m \cdot 5^n$
where $0 < x < 32$
and $0 < m < 32$
and $0 < n < 32$

This has to do with computational efficiency so I want to know if the decimal or binary representations of $x$ can answer the question rather than having to extract factors by brute force as follows:

Iterate $i$ from $2$ to $\operatorname{ceiling}(\sqrt n)$ where $i$ is a power of $2$ or a power of $5$ or a product of either.

Brute force performance is acceptable for 32-bit integers but slows down exponentially as the size of the integers increase. I will be dealing with numbers around the order of $2^{1,024}$.

**NOTE:** I do not need the actual factors.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Editing the question to reflect them being NOT the same.

Comment: You can write $2^m\cdot 5^n$ or $2^m\times 5^n$.  Writing $2^m*5^m$ is a workaround for situations where one is restricted to the characters on the keyboard.  I changed that and I also changed $ceiling(sqrt(n))$ to $\operatorname{ceiling}(\sqrt n)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: MichaelHardy: Thank you. These edits are very helpful in learning/using Latex.

Answer (score 0):

If the exponents are $2^n$ and $5^m$ then the number $2^n 5^m$ will have $\min\{m,n\}$ trailing zero digits in decimal (base 10) representation.

Comment: Can I also assume the inverse? That is if $x$ in base 10 has a minimum of or exactly $min(m,n)$ trailing zeros, then $x$ is definitely a product of $2^m5^n$?

Comment: That is a consequence of the prime factorization. Every trailing zero needs one factor $2$ and one factor $5$. So $5000$ must have at least the factor $2^3 5^3$.

Comment: No: $10=2\cdot5$ has one trailing zero, but so does $30=3\cdot 2\cdot 5$, which is not a product of only 2s and 5s.

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastest ways is:

- Write $x$ as the product of a power of $2$ and a power of $5$ : $x = 2^{m} 5^{n}$
- Check if $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

Given $x$ compute,

($x \mod 4$, $x \mod 25$)

If both are zero, then $x$ has $2^m$ and $5^n$ as factors for some $m >= 2, n >= 2$. Since you don't need the actual factors, this would be the fastest.